# Unable SSH connect due to public key not found

Tags: ssh

Here's the command I run `ssh callydai@callydai.com -v`

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to callydai.com [107.180.55.15] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/raigovind93/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

The key is definitely there:

```
~/.ssh  => tree
.
├── github_rsa
├── github_rsa.pub
├── id_rsa
├── id_rsa.pub
├── known_hosts
└── known_hosts.old
```

How can I get the SSH command to recognize the key_load_public?

Answer (score 1):

Those things have absolutely nothing to do with each other. As you can see from the log,

1. the server breaks the connection abruptly without actually *saying* "Access denied" (note the "Connection reset by peer" message);
2. this happens before reaching the authentication stage – in fact, it happens so early that the server doesn't even have a chance to *start* the SSH protocol (a similar "SSH-2.0-something" line is expected).

Also, the error message is slightly confusing, but it actually talks about ssh being unable to find the *certificate* file `id_rsa.pub-cert` – which is an optional addition used by some corporate networks. You don't actually need the `-cert` file 99% of the time. (Since ssh says `…/id_rsa type 1` that means it *did* recognize the plain key.)

So where does the connection failure come from? Can't answer without at least seeing the server's system logs. For example, if you have Denyhosts installed, make sure you didn't accidentally cause it to put yourself in the deny list.

Comment: I am able to ping the host and receive packets, is that different from Denyhosts?

Comment: I called up godaddy. IP address was blocked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, Denyhosts has nothing to do with ICMP ping packets – it only blocks the specific applications (in this case, SSH).